# Consulta SQL devuelve valores incompletos

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta `SQL` que me devuelve valores incompletos

La conexión con el `server` se hace a traves de **odbc_connect**, y para obtener las rows **odbc_fetch_array**

La consulta es parecida a la siguiente

```
$conn = odbc_connect(__ODBC_NAME__,__ODBC_USER__,__ODBC_PASSWORD__);

$sql = "SELECT 
        codigo AS CODE, 
        login AS LOGIN, 
        nombre AS NAME,
        'Comercial' AS ROLE
    FROM usuarios
    WHERE codigo != ''";

$ret = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
$ar = odbc_fetch_array($ret);
    
    // Array devuelto de ejemplo
    /* array (
           [CODE] => 5
           [LOGIN] => email@gma
           [NAME] => VICENT
           [ROLE] => Comerc
       )*/

    // El ODBC es MultiBase/ODBC64 (Multiway)
```

Al pintar el array, me muestra algo parecido a lo que os muestro arriba, los datos se cortan a partir de cierto número de caracteres. Lo curioso es que incluso el campo `ROLE` que usa un literal, también lo corta

Es un poco ambigua la pregunta, pero llevo horas y no se por donde tirar, alguna idea?

**Edit**

He probado a hacer la consulta con todos los campos `SELECT * FROM.....` y devuelve algunos caracteres más, pero lo sigue cortando. Rarísimo

Comment: Asi como esta, es dificil saber que pasa. puede ser un problema de conexion? o que los datos esten incompletos en la db?

Comment: Los datos si están completos en DB, ya que los he comprobado desde un visor SQL, se que es un poco vaga la pregunta, pero no se por dónde empezar a mirar

Comment: Entonces habria que ver el codigo con el que traes los datos, y como los mostras por pantalla...

Comment: MySql  o sql-server?

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con un poco más de información

Comment: Yo apostaría que el culpable es el driver ODBC, o alguna configuración de este

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando hay problemas con datos truncados, intenta configurar `ODBC Long Read Length`, mediante:

- [`odbc.defaultlrl`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/odbc.configuration.php#ini.uodbc.defaultlrl) en `php.ini` o mediante [`ini_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ini-set), por ejemplo:

  ```
  ini_set("odbc.defaultlrl", 65536); // 64Kb
  ```
- [`odbc_longreadlen(resource $result_id , int $length)`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.odbc-longreadlen.php) (*recomiendo leer los comentarios en la doc*)

  ```
  odbc_longreadlen($ret, 65536);
  ```